# Getting NullPonterException while trying to stop apache-activemq?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jmx

I am unable to shutdown my activemq gracefully after enabling jmx. Please help and tell me what am I doing wrong. Here is what I am trying to do.

**start activemq:-**

```
[mwapp@JMNGD1BAO150V02 ~]$ /app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/bin/activemq start xbean:/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/conf/activemq-security.xml
INFO: Loading '/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/java/jre1.7.0_79//bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//data/activemq.pid' (pid '16917')
```

**activemq.log:-** To me it's looking fine

```
2017-10-12 13:48:18,936 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@2142b533: startup date [Thu Oct 12 13:48:18 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2017-10-12 13:48:20,008 | INFO  | Loading properties file from URL [file:/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//conf/credentials-enc.properties] | org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer | main
2017-10-12 13:48:20,975 | INFO  | Loaded the Bouncy Castle security provider. | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2017-10-12 13:48:21,283 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/jms_nas/kahadb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2017-10-12 13:48:21,308 | INFO  | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext | JMX connector
2017-10-12 13:48:21,594 | INFO  | KahaDB is version 6 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2017-10-12 13:48:21,653 | INFO  | Recovering from the journal @1105:27118028 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2017-10-12 13:48:21,657 | INFO  | Recovery replayed 58 operations from the journal in 0.046 seconds. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2017-10-12 13:48:21,719 | INFO  | PListStore:[/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2017-10-12 13:48:21,903 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:JMNGD1BAO150V02-59661-1507796301746-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2017-10-12 13:48:22,786 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: ssl://JMNGD1BAO150V02:61616?needClientAuth=true&maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2017-10-12 13:48:22,787 | INFO  | Connector ssl started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2017-10-12 13:48:22,787 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0 (localhost, ID:JMNGD1BAO150V02-59661-1507796301746-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2017-10-12 13:48:22,787 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2017-10-12 13:48:22,788 | WARN  | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 1397 mb). The data directory: /jms_nas/kahadb only has 91534 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 91534 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2017-10-12 13:48:23,646 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /admin | main
2017-10-12 13:48:23,755 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://localhost:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2017-10-12 13:48:23,755 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2017-10-12 13:48:23,799 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
2017-10-12 13:48:24,068 | INFO  | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath | /api | main
2017-10-12 13:48:24,185 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml | /api | main
```

**stop activemq:-**

```
[mwapp@JMNGD1BAO150V02 ~]$ /app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/bin/activemq stop xbean:/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/conf/activemq-security.xml
INFO: Loading '/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/java/jre1.7.0_79//bin/java'
INFO: Waiting at least 30 seconds for regular process termination of pid '16917' :
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_79 /usr/java/jre1.7.0_79
  Heap sizes: current=63488k  free=61608k  max=932352k
    JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//conf/login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//conf:/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/ -Dactivemq.base=/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/ -Dactivemq.conf=/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//conf -Dactivemq.data=/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0//data
Extensions classpath:
  [/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/lib,/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/lib/camel,/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/lib/optional,/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/lib/web,/app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /app/apache-activemq-5.14.0
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /app/apache-activemq-5.14.0
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /app/apache-activemq-5.14.0/data
Connecting to JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.handleException(AbstractCommand.java:167)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractJmxCommand.execute(AbstractJmxCommand.java:390)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
...............................
INFO: Regular shutdown not successful,  sending SIGKILL to process
INFO: sending SIGKILL to pid '16917'
```

As you can see, the system is forcefully shutting down using pid which is not expected. I am currently using ***apache-activemq-5.14.0*** and the configuration file will look something like below. I am not sure why activemq gave two separate file to enable JMX i.e. `env` and `activemq-security.xml`. Or the `env` file has some different role to play. I read the documentation, and I got more confuse when they mention from V.5.12.0 onwards they are supporting OCSP. Do I need to enable that too?

**${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/bin/env**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Active MQ installation dirs
# ACTIVEMQ_HOME="<Installationdir>/"
# ACTIVEMQ_BASE="$ACTIVEMQ_HOME"
# ACTIVEMQ_CONF="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/conf"
# ACTIVEMQ_DATA="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/data"
# ACTIVEMQ_TMP="$ACTIVEMQ_BASE/tmp"
ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms64M -Xmx1G"
if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS" ] ; then
    ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/login.config"
fi
#ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS -Dorg.apache.activemq.audit=true"
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099"
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access"
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true"
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
#ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_CONTROL="--jmxurl service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/jmxrmi --jmxuser controlRole --jmxpassword abcd1234"
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_CONTROL=""
if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_QUEUEMANAGERURL" ]; then
    ACTIVEMQ_QUEUEMANAGERURL="--amqurl tcp://localhost:61616"
fi
if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS" ] ; then
    #ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS="-Djava.security.properties=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/java.security"
    ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS=""
fi
#ACTIVEMQ_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
if [ -z "$ACTIVEMQ_KILL_MAXSECONDS" ]; then
    ACTIVEMQ_KILL_MAXSECONDS=30
fi
ACTIVEMQ_USER=""
# ACTIVEMQ_PIDFILE="$ACTIVEMQ_DATA/activemq.pid"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.7.0_79/"
```

**${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/activemq-security.xml**

```
  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
    ----------------------------------------------
    <managementContext>
      <!--managementContext createConnector="true" connectorPort="1099"/-->
        <managementContext createConnector="true">
                <property xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" name="environment">
                        <map xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
                                <entry xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" key="jmx.remote.x.password.file" value="${activemq.base}/conf/jmx.password"/>
                                <entry xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" key="jmx.remote.x.access.file" value="${activemq.base}/conf/jmx.access"/>
                        </map>
                </property>
        </managementContext>
    </managementContext>

    ----------------------------------------------

    <shutdownHooks>
      <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook"/>
    </shutdownHooks>
  </broker>
```

Comment: Maybe try to upgrade and use a newer version

Comment: So, is it possible to upgrade using Linux command line?